# Cleaning after git merge --no-ff

Tags: git

Two branches - `master` and `feature` - were merged with `git merge --no-ff`. Later `feature` branch was removed. The tree looks like that:

```
*      (master) A new feature added to the master
|\
| *        yet another small commit
| *        another small commit 
| *        small commit
|/
*      Master before the feature was added
```

I would like to cleanup those small commits from the tree so it looks like:

```
*      (master) A new feature added to the master
*      Master before the feature was added
```

How to do that? The local repo was not yet pushed.

Comment: `git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do

```
git checkout master
git reset --soft <HASH of commit "Master before the feature was added">
git commit -m "A new feature added to the master"
```

Alternatively you could use

```
git commit -c ORIG_HEAD
```

to reuse the commit message from your original merge commit.

Comment: Nice one. I'm wondering are there any difference in git internals between my epic reseting and merging solution and your fast trick?

Comment: We should get pretty same results, I think. Your solution preserves the feature branch, though.

Comment: Add: `-c` (or even `-C`) with the original merge commit ID to copy the log message (and with `-C`, author as well).  This is a bit easier if you create a temporary name, such as a tag that you delete again afterward, to hang on to the merge-commit-ID.  @janisz: internally the squash-merge has to repeat the whole merge process, while this method just uses the result of the regular merge.  The squash-merge's top level tree will exactly match the regular-merge's top level tree (assuming any conflicts, if there are any, are handled the same way) so the results are equivalent.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the `-c` hint! I added it to the answer.

Comment: @torek Thanks. So this is the best answer, it don't require solving conflicts again. I thought about using rebase interactive but it won't work for this tree

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that your repo looks like this (I need commits SHAs)

```
*   82daefb - (HEAD, master) A new feature added to the master (15 seconds ago) 
|\  
| * 6e156b0 -  yet another small commit (84 seconds ago) 
| * ccc4753 - another small commit (2 minutes ago) 
| * e76a659 - small commit (2 minutes ago) 
|/  
* 3041679 - Master before the feature was added (2 minutes ago)
```

1. Recover your feature branch 
   `git checkout -b feature && git reset --hard 6e156b0`
2. Reset maser to *3041679* `git co master && git reset --hard 3041679`
3. Merge your branches `git merge feature --squash`
4. Commit merge `git commit -m "A new feature added to the master"`

finally your tree will look like

```
* 6bf734c - (HEAD, master) A new feature added to the master (68 seconds ago)
* 3041679 - Master before the feature was added (5 minutes ago)
```